# Java beans, annotations: What do they do? How do they help me?

Tags: java, design-patterns, annotations, javabeans

Here is what what I understand so far:

Java beans are just to help other things (visual things?) interact with your code.  I think that this is mostly for UI stuff because it is easier to design this visually.  Is it bad practice to use Java beans for non-UI things?

Java beans have getter and setter methods (bad OOP practice) and are serializable.

In terms of annotations, I think that user defined annotations do not provide any functionality.  Some annotations like @depretiated raise compiler warnings.  Can user defined annotations do this somehow?  Are user defined annotations good for anything other than documentation?  How can I use them?  Does eclipse or intellij have some feature that involves annotations?

Have a good weekend.

Jake

**Update:**  that is starting to make more sense.  Could someone refer me to an example of when it would be appropriate to use the java bean format and when it would not?

Also I read somewhere that several classes can be a bean and it is a way of packaging classes.

Just to clarify one more thing.  I am 95% sure that being a java bean is somewhat like being a singleton (or other pattern).  It does not affect what the compiler does.

Comment: How are getter/setter method bad OOP practice? This makes no sense. Don't you just mean that they're too verbose/boilerplate-code-producend? Then just use a decent IDE which can autogenerate all that stuff for you in a few clicks with only property names as input.

Comment: Some argue that certain uses of getters/setters violate the encapsulation principle... i.e. "Don't ask for the information you need to do the work; ask the object that has the information to do the work for you." from http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-2003/jw-0905-toolbox.html?page=3.

Comment: @James: Yeah its more common in DDD.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Annotations are a form of [declaritive programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming). First, you have to grok the benefits of declaritive programming before the utility of annotations becomes clear. In essence, you can add functionality or behavior to a block of code simply by "declaring" that it has a certain characteristic. This is in contrast to actually writing out a series of statements to apply or setup the same behavior.

The [JPA annotations](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/ias/toplink/jpa/resources/toplink-jpa-annotations.html) are an example of adding functionality with annotations. I don't know of "user created" example off the top of my head, but the JPA annotations are implemented exactly the same way that you or I would do it.

As far as Java Beans, the original use of them was for GUI-programming. The "easy" way of using JavaBeans was to use naming conventions to define the "attributes" of a bean--hence getters and setters. As far as I know, JavaBeans were originally an implementation for GUI-based editing of forms and UI's. So the getters and setters made it easy for the UI software to discover user-viewable or editable attributes. With a Bean Descriptor you can change the way descriptors work a bit...

The reason they persist to this day is they provide a de facto way to inspect objects for publicly exposed properties. It is not bad form to use JavaBeans outside of a GUI. The preference in Java seems to be to use the no arg constructor and then inject your dependencies rather than using RAII style of programming (not that it's strictly available)...

It's actually quite common, particuarly if the object will be manipulated by code that does not know a priori the object it will be manipulating (take a look at [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) for a good example).

Comment: Awesome, starting to get a hold on Java beans.  But still a bit shaky on what the annotations do.  Do annotations affect the compiled code?    Or are they just instructions for programmers.  Do they work in a similar way to an interface (and force the programmer with compiler errors) to implement certain methods/follow certain standards?  Would it be better to open a new question for this?  Happy Monday!

Comment: All of the above. I would recommend opening a new Q specifically talking about annotations.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you're confusing Java beans and EJB (Enterprise Java Beans) - these are different concepts. Actually they're almost the same now, but this was not always so - the history is rather confusing.

James gives a good explanation of the history of Java beans - they're much older than annotations (which were introduced in Java 1.5). EJBs are also much older, but they have been radically revised and are now basically Java beans with special annotations running in an EJB container.

This is actually a perfect example for how useful annotations can be.

"Old style" EJBs (prior to version 3 of the spec) were *horrible* to code. You needed to define (IIRC) two interfaces, one implementation class (that did not actually implement the interfaces) and an XML descriptor that linked them together. And if you made a typo anywhere, there was no compiler error - just a totally cryptic runtime error that did not help you narrow down the problem.

Why was this so? Because it allowed the EJB container to control how the actual implementation code was called, and to transparently do things like access control, transactions and replication.

In the EJB 3.0 spec, this was simplified radically, so that now you need only one class (which can be a "classic" Java Bean in the case of entity beans), which actually implements the EJB's logic - and annotations that tell the EJB container how to treat it. Instead of a separate XML file, information about the code lives right next to the code itself in the same file, and since annotation syntax is checked by the compiler, many potential errors are caught at compile time.

Comment: ok, so I think what you are saying is there are two kinds of beans.  In EJBs, the annotations are processed by the compiler but otherwise they are not?  Does this mean that to compile an EJB you need a special compiler?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: No, EJB annotations are processed by the EJB container at runtime. But they're still part of the code and are checked for syntax errors by the compiler (which then puts them into the class files, where they're accessible through reflection). Old-style EJBs had their metadata in XML descriptors, which the Java compiler obviously did not know about and thus could not check.

Comment: Annotations *can* be used to influence the compiler, e.g. @Override - but this is really a less important use case than annotations used at runtime (because few people write compilers).

Comment: My understanding of the @Override was just that it informed the programmer that a method was overridden (and issued a warning/error if the programmer used it incorrectly).  I didn't think that it changed the function of the code..  Is this what you mean?

Comment: Never mind.  For anyone else wondering about annotations have a glance here: it is an awesome explanation: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/annotations.html

Answer (score 1):

JUnit uses annotations since version 4 of JUnit. That is an example of user-defined annotations. You add the @Test-annotation to a method and the JUnit-framework recognizes it and executes the method as test.

Beans will be used by some frameworks to work with otherwise unknown objects. An examples that comes to my mind are persistance-frameworks, they duplicate some registered objects into databases and uses the bean-properties for that.

Comment: Huh, ok that is pretty interesting.  I use version 3 so I didn't know that.  How does JUNIT detect that there is an annotation?  Can I detect that too?  (Not sure why I would want to detect that but..)

Thanks, enjoy your monday

Comment: <code>
for (Method m : Class.forName(args[0]).getMethods()) {
   if (m.isAnnotationPresent(Test.class)) {
      ...
   }
}
</code>
Looks like that code will do it.

Comment: Exactly, the Java-reflection-API also allows you to look up the annotations. That's a possibility to extend the language to a little degree: You can add your own annotations.